# Modify content of large file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter

I have extract my tables from my database in json file, now I want to read this files and remove all double quotes on them, seems easy and tried hundred of solutions, and some take me to the out of memory problems. I'm dealing with files that they have more than 1Gb size.The code that you will find below have a strange behaviour, and I don't understand why it return empty files

```
  public void replaceDoubleQuotes(String fileName){
    log.debug(" start formatting " + fileName + " ...");
    File firstFile = new File ("C:/sqlite/db/tables/" + fileName);
    String oldContent = "";
    String newContent = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    FileWriter writerFile = null;
    String stringQuotes = "\\\\\\\\\"";
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(firstFile));
        writerFile = new FileWriter("C:/sqlite/db/tables/" + fileName);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(writerFile);
        
    while   (( oldContent = reader.readLine()) != null ){
        newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(stringQuotes, "");
        writer.write(newContent);
        }
    
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

and when I try to use `FileWriter(path,true)` to write at the end of the file the program don't stop increasing the file memory till the hard disk will be full, thanks for help

ps : I also tried to use subString and append the new content and after the while I write the subString but also doesn't work

Comment: You appear to be treating a database file as if it is made up of lines of text.  I don't know anything about SQLite, but that seems to be unlikely.

Comment: I wondered also about what db usually dumps its data in JSON format, but I figured it's beside the point of the question. Would still be nice to know.

Comment: Source file `new File ("C:/sqlite/db/tables/" + fileName)` is the same as destination `new FileWriter("C:/sqlite/db/tables/" + fileName)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL; DR;

Do not read and write the same file concurrently.

### The issue

Your code starts reading, and then immediately truncates  the file it is reading.

```
 reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(firstFile));
 writerFile = new FileWriter("C:/sqlite/db/tables/" + fileName);
 writer = new BufferedWriter(writerFile);
```

The first line opens a read handle to the file.
The second line opens a write handle to the same file.
It is not very clear if you look at the documentation of FileWriter constructor, but when you do not use a constructor that allows you to specify the `append` parameter, then the value is `false` by default, meaning, you immediately truncate the file if it already exists.

At this point (line 2) you have just erased the file you were about to read. So you end up with an empty file.

### What about using append=true

Well, then the file is not erased when it is created, which is "good". So you program starts reading the first line, and outputs (to the same file) the filtered version.

So each time a line is read, another is appended.

No wonder your program will never reach the end of the file : each time it advances a line, it creates another line to process. Generally speaking, you'll never reach end of file (well of course if the file is a single line to begin with, you might but that's a corner case).

### The solution

Write to a temporary file, and IF (and only IF) you succed, then swap the files if you really need too.

An advantage of this solution : if for whatever reason your processe crahses, you'll have the original file untouched and you could retry later, which is usually a good thing. Your process is "repeatable".

A disadvantage : you'll need twice the space at some point. (Although you could compress the temp file and reduce this factor but still).

## About out of memory issues

When working with arbitrarily  large files, the path you chose (using buffered readers and writers) is the right one, because you only use one line-worth of memory at a time.

Therefore it generally avoids memory usage issues (unless of course, you have a file without line breaks, in which case it makes no difference at all).

Other solutions, involving reading the whole file at once, then performing the search/replace in memory, then writing the contents back do not scale that well, so it's good you avoided this kind of computation.

## Not related but important

Check out the [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to properly close your resources (reader / writer). Here you forgot to close the reader, and you are not closing the writer appropriately anyway (that is : in a finally clause).

Another thing : I'm pretty sure no java program written by a mere mortal will beat tools like `sed` or `awk` that are available on most unix platforms (and some more). Maybe you'd want to check if rolling your own in java is worth what is a shell one-liner.

Comment: This is a great answer, and very well explained. It would likely be worth mentioning that reading 1GB into heap isn't a good idea and OP should probably read portions of the file at a time.

Comment: OP is using a BufferedReader wich reads one line at a time, and not the whole file (assuming the file is not a single line, wich is another issue). I'll add a sidenote, because of the explicit mention of an OutOfMemory, but I feel like the question is not so much about that particular issue.

Comment: Yeah that is a great point, but likely if the suggestion is to read and then write then I can only assume they will read all then write all which could be an issue. None the less, this is a great answer and yes, your answer is more centered around the problem.

Comment: @Jason -  They can (and should) still read and write linewise. The output file can be given a temporary name, and then renamed on successful completion of the file.

Comment: thank you for the answer and for the explanations, I'm consuming now more resources on the disk cause Im writing in separate files, but is ok for the moment. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

@GPI already provided a great answer on why reading and writing concurrently is causing the issue you're experiencing. It is also worth noting that reading 1gb of data into heap at once can definitely cause a `OutOfMemoryError` if enough heap isn't allocated which is likely. To solve this problem you could use an `InputStream` and read chunks of the file at a time, then write to another file until the process is completed, and ultimately replace the existing file with the modified one and delete. With this approach you could even use a `ForkJoinTask` to help with this since it's such a large job.

**Side note;**
There may be a better solution than `create new file, write to new file, replace existing, delete new file`.

Comment: Since the dump is a JSON file of some kind of DB, I'd be cautious with recommending a multithreading approach. First because it's not even sure that the `replaceAll` is a bottleneck (compared to disk IO), second because in a DB dump, line ordering may be important, and maintaining the ordering and parallelizing at the same time looks like a big headache. So I'd really check if the perf boost is actually so important it's worth the trouble.

Comment: `BufferedReader` has a default buffer which is used to allocate desired memory for reading, this size could be adjusted once you construct it. `OutOfMemoryError` should not be the topic here.

Comment: @GBI great point, it may not be worth it. Traychoivanov, okay that is fair. +1